# Traefik ECS provider is not forwarding client IP with AWS ALB

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to fix this issue for the past 2 days but I don't know how to resolve it. I wanted to capture the client IP on the application with traefik proxy.

**Setup:**

R53 --> ALB --> (Traefik proxy --> applocation) ECS

I'm running my application on ECS and leveraging ECS provider.

What I have tried :

Adding the below labels to the traefik as per the documents:

```
--entrypoints.http.forwardedheaders.trustedips=0.0.0.0/0
--entrypoints.https.forwardedheaders.trustedips=0.0.0.0/0
--entrypoints.http.forwardedheaders.insecure=true
--entrypoints.https.forwardedheaders.insecure=true
```

Tried all of them together and individually also but every time I add these configurations traefik stopped working without any useful logs.

**What I observed:**

Without adding any of these configurations if I hit the trafik IP directly by skipping the Loadbalancer I can see My IP (client-IP). does it mean i need to make changes in the AWS-ALB ?

**Through LB:**

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-620e68b5-121181407c9ceadf6c8f0a25
X-Forwarded-For: 172.31.22.81
X-Forwarded-Host: infra.**********.nl
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: ip-172-31-8-140.eu-central-1.compute.internal
X-Real-Ip: 172.31.22.81
```

**Directly IP HIT:**

```
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Forwarded-For: 80.***.***.61
X-Forwarded-Host: 3.71.93.123
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: ip-172-31-8-140.eu-central-1.compute.internal
X-Real-Ip: 80.***.***.61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a way to do achieve this after reading tons of documents and testing.

This is for ECS provider:

**Task definitions :**

`Traefik`

```
        "traefik",
        "--providers.ecs.clusters=application",
        "--log.level=DEBUG",
        "--providers.ecs.region=us-west-2",
        "--api.insecure",
        "--entryPoints.web.address=:80",
        "--entryPoints.web.proxyProtocol.trustedIPs=127.0.0.1/32,<VPC-CIDR>",
        "--entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs=127.0.0.1/32,<VPC-CIDR>",
```

`application`:

```
        "traefik.http.routers.app.rule": "pathprefix(`/`)",
        "traefik.enable": "true",
        "traefik.http.services.service-app-app.loadbalancer.healthcheck.timeout": "10",
        "traefik.http.services.service-app-app.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie": "true",
        "traefik.http.services.service-app-app.loadbalancer.healthcheck.port": "8080",
        "traefik.http.services.service-app-app.loadbalancer.healthcheck.interval": "30",
        "traefik.http.services.service-app-app.loadbalancer.healthcheck.path": "/ping",
        "traefik.http.services.service-app-app.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie.name": "app-cookie"
```

With Who-ami container:

```
Hostname: ip-172-31-29-79.us-east-2.compute.internal
IP: 127.0.0.1
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-623af218-525fa18d4d17e1ef431bb2b9
X-Forwarded-For: 8*******5, 172.31.12.125
X-Forwarded-Host: ecs-*****.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: ip-172-31-15-101.us-east-2.compute.internal
X-Real-Ip: <loadbalancer-IP>
```

This PR gives a good overview of how the forward header works
https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/7875/files

How it works:

```
X-Forwarded-For: <client_ip>, <alb_ip>
X-Real-Ip: <alb_ip>
```